# What are command, data and comp ring in vmxnet3 PMD in DPDK

Tags: vmware, dpdk

I am starting to work and understand the basics of DPDK and it's working with VMWare (VMXNET3 PMD). I started browsing through the code base and found reference to 3 ring structures in vmxnet3_tx_queue_t (at vmxnet3_ring.h), namely cmd_ring, data_ring and comp_ring.

I tried surfing to understand the use case and working of them, but didn't get quite get the documentation on it or was unable to understand.

Any pointers / direction would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vmxnet3` is pretty decently described in the DPDK NIC documentation:
http://doc.dpdk.org/guides/nics/vmxnet3.html

> The driver pre-allocates the packet buffers and loads the command ring descriptors in advance. The hypervisor fills those packet buffers on packet arrival and write completion ring descriptors, which are eventually pulled by the PMD. After reception, the DPDK application frees the descriptors and loads new packet buffers for the coming packets.
>
> In the transmit routine, the DPDK application fills packet buffer pointers in the descriptors of the command ring and notifies the hypervisor. In response the hypervisor takes packets and passes them to the vSwitch, It writes into the completion descriptors ring. The rings are read by the PMD in the next transmit routine call and the buffers and descriptors are freed from memory.

Not sure though if those details are the "basics of DPDK", as those low level queues are abstracted by the DPDK Poll Mode Driver API:

https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/prog_guide/poll_mode_drv.html

So you better refer this document and use this API, as you won't be able to use `vmxnet3` rings directly in your app anyway...

Comment: Thanks or the inputs, and it was useful. I was trying to understand the flow of vmxnet3 driver in itself, and so was also interested in the working of the rings.